# Написать запрос на отбор данных(PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql

Необходимо посчитать количество подписок и отписок за каждый день.

Для этого необходимо сравнивать наличие профилей пользователей по текущему и прошлому дню(например, 25 и 26 числа, 26 и 27) и выводить данные для текущего дня(26, 27):

```
если в прошлом дне есть профиль,а в текущем нет - отписка, наоборот - подписка.
если профиль присутствует в в обоих днях, то не относится ни к подпискам и отпискам.
```

Необходимые данные предоставлены по ссылке https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5a4683fa935b2b438500be733ba17f7e

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0c8ace94dd09ff2a5eb2ebcce51a2476)

Исходная таблица:

```
create table instagram_account_followers
(
  instagram_profile_id bigint    not null,
  created_at           timestamp(0) with time zone
);
```

Исходные данные:

```
INSERT INTO "instagram_account_followers" ("instagram_profile_id", "created_at") VALUES 
(1, '2018-06-27 00:00:00'),
(2, '2018-06-27 00:00:00'),
(3, '2018-06-27 00:00:00'),
(4, '2018-06-27 00:00:00'),
(5, '2018-06-27 00:00:00'),
(4, '2018-06-28 00:00:00'),
(5, '2018-06-28 00:00:00'),
(6, '2018-06-28 00:00:00'),
(7, '2018-06-28 00:00:00'),
(8, '2018-06-28 00:00:00'),
(7, '2018-06-29 00:00:00'),
(8, '2018-06-29 00:00:00');
```

Запрос (отформатирован):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1, t2) t
     , SUM(CASE WHEN p2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "pod"
     , SUM(CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "ot"
FROM ( SELECT t1.created_at t1
            , t1.instagram_profile_id p1
            , t2.created_at + INTERVAL '1 day' t2
            , t2.instagram_profile_id p2
       FROM instagram_account_followers t1
       FULL JOIN instagram_account_followers t2 
              ON t1.instagram_profile_id = t2.instagram_profile_id 
             AND t1.created_at = t2.created_at + INTERVAL '1 day'
       WHERE t1.created_at IS NULL 
          OR t2.created_at IS NULL     
     ) subquery
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t;
```

Результат:

```
t                        pod   ot
2018-06-27 00:00:00+01   5     0
2018-06-28 00:00:00+01   3     3
2018-06-29 00:00:00+01   0     3
2018-06-30 00:00:00+01   0     2
```

При необходимости в итоговом запросе (или прямо в подзапросе) можно отфильтровать записи, у которых дата больше максимальной даты в исходной таблице, чтобы убрать последнюю запись (а надо ли? баланс-то не сойдётся...). Также можно переписать с подзапроса на WITH.

**UPDATE**

> есть в этой же таблице поле instagram_account_id, мне нужно все это дело выводить по аккаунту

```
WITH cte1 (t1, p1, t2, p2, a1) AS 
( SELECT t1.created_at,
         t1.instagram_profile_id, 
         t2.created_at + INTERVAL '1 day',
         t2.instagram_profile_id,
         COALESCE(t1.instagram_account_id, t2.instagram_account_id)
  FROM instagram_account_followers t1
  FULL JOIN instagram_account_followers t2 
         ON t1.instagram_profile_id = t2.instagram_profile_id 
        AND t1.created_at = t2.created_at + INTERVAL '1 day'
        AND t1.instagram_account_id = t2.instagram_account_id
  WHERE (   t1.created_at IS NULL
         OR t2.created_at IS NULL) 
),
cte2 ("date", subscriptions, unsubscribe, account, rn) AS
( SELECT COALESCE(t1, t2)::date "date", 
         SUM(CASE WHEN p2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
         SUM(CASE WHEN p1 IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE 0 END),
         a1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1 ORDER BY COALESCE(t1, t2)::date DESC)
  FROM cte1
  GROUP BY "date", a1
)
SELECT account, "date", subscriptions, unsubscribe 
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn > 1
ORDER BY account, "date";
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1252c6821740b1f7ea17104b470c769a)

Comment: @ВиталийШонов *почему должен баланс не сойтись, если убрать?* Ну как бы если мы берём ВСЕ записи из таблицы, то общее количество подписок должно быть равно общему количеству отписок, не так ли? До данных - подписок нет, после - тоже нет, так что никуда не деваться. Что собсно и показывает результат - сумма по каждой из колонок равна 8. *мне бы желательно без последней записи* Ну убери эту запись... Отсортируй по убыванию даты и возьми `LIMIT ALL OFFSET 1`.

Comment: @ВиталийШонов *я думал, что он вообще не может быть null* В исходных данных - да. А вот после `FULL JOIN` - очень даже может... А `SUM(CASE...` - это простой подсчёт записей, отвечающих условию.

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Comment: @ВиталийШонов *а посчитать все подписки и отписки* По дате? кто мешает... [GROUPING SETS, CUBE, and ROLLUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS).

Comment: Какая разница - по аккаунту, по дате, и то и другое... ссылка на доку будет одна и та же.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY status) FROM
(
    SELECT t1.instagram_account_id, 
        CASE WHEN t2.created_at IS NOT NUL THEN 'unsubscribing' ELSE 'subscription' END AS status FROM subscription_table t1
    LEFT JOIN subscription_table t2 ON t1.instagram_profile_id = t2.instagram_profile_id
    WHERE (t1.created_at - INTERVAL '1' DAY)::DATE = t2.created_at::DATE
) AS s
```

Comment: Количество добавил а вот с профилем в прошлом дне не понял

Comment: используйте устловие в верхнем запросе: status = 'unsubscribing' или status = 'subscription'